# why is array(className,"privateFunctionName") returning the private function?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-replace-callback

```
class someClass
{
    public function truncate($content, $amount = false)
    {

        if (!$amount || preg_match_all("/\s+/", $content, $junk) <= $amount) return $content;

        $content = preg_replace_callback("/(<\/?[^>]+\s+[^>]*>)/", array($this, '_shield'), $content);

        ......

        return $truncate;
    }

    ... 

    private function _shield($matches)
    {
        return preg_replace("/\s/", "\x01", $matches[0]);
    }

    ...

    private function _unshield($strings)
    {
        return preg_replace("/\x01/", " ", $strings);
    }

    ...
}
```

According to [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), the 2nd parameter of `preg_replace_callback` should be a handler function, in the above code it is `array($this, '_shield')`, which I believe returns one of the class's private functions "_shield". Can someone explain to me why `array(class,privateFunctionName)` would return the private function? Is there a PHP manual page regarding this?

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual, the second parameter should be a **callable** (as defined in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)), and `array($this, '_shield')` is right that: it determines that `$this->_shield()`  should be used as the function to handle the replacement

Comment: My question is how `array($this,'_shield')` gets translated to `$this->_shield()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the examples for [Callbacks / Callables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php#language.types.callable) you see the different ways to specify an object and class method `array($object, 'method')` and `array('className', 'method')`.

If you're wanting to know why this works with private methods, it's because `$this` is the current object and of course has access to it's own private methods.

`array('someDifferentClass', '_shield')` and `array($someDifferentObj, '_shield')` would NOT work if `_shield()` was `private` in the other class.

You can also use anonymous functions:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback("/(<\/?[^>]+\s+[^>]*>)/",
                                 function($v) {
                                     return $this->_shield($v);
                                 }, $content);
```

> What got me here is `array(1,2)` would return an array `[1,2]`, then why `array($object, 'method')` would return the method instead of an array with `$object` being its first element and string 'method' being the second?

It does return an array with `$object` being its first element and string 'method' being the second.  But then `preg_replace_callback` uses those pieces of information in the array to call the method.  You can do the same in PHP:

```
    $method = array($this, '_shield');
    $truncate = ${$method[0]}->{$method[1]}($content);
```

Comment: What got me here is array(1,2) would return an array [1,2], then why array($object, 'method') would return the method instead of an array with $object being its first element and string 'method' being the second?